# how to extract file path from QFileSystemModel?

Tags: pyqt4, qfilesystemmodel

```
 def nukeScriptFolder(self, index = QModelIndex()):

         index = self.dirmodel.index(QDir.currentPath())

         fileInfo = QtCore.QFileInfo(self.dirmodel.fileInfo(index))
         #print fileInfo.fileName()        
         #path = self.dirmodel.fileinfo(index).absoluteFilePath()
         self.fileView.setRootIndex(filemodel.setRootPath(path))
```

When I execute the above code I get the following error

```
     path_index = self.dirmodel.index(QDir.currentPath()).toString()
     TypeError: 'sip.methoddescriptor' object is not callable
```

Comment: What exact versions of Python, PyQt4, Sip, and Qt are you using, and on which platform?

Comment: python 2.6, sip-4.13.1, PyQt4 ,Qt -4.7.4 on windows.

Comment: What _exact_ version of Python-2.6 and PyQt4? This may be due to a bug (most probably in Python).

Comment: i got the solution , that wasn't the bug... its the error that occurs when the object is not available globally

Comment: thank you very much for your efforts